# email when images change, woocommerce product

Tags: image, woocommerce, notifications, product, gallery

I am attempting to send out an email anytime a woocommerce product has its images changed in any way.

I started off by attempting to get the $_POST of the image gallery, but I think I am calling it the wrong thing… I have tried the following:
$images = $_POST[‘image_ids’];
$images = $_POST[‘gallery_image_ids’];

Then I am comparing that value to the current image ids:
$oldImages = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

If they do not match I am using wp_mail to send an email to various people.

I am doing all this inside a custom php function using:
add_action(‘pre_post_update’, ‘content_change_email’, 10, 2);
function content_change_email($post_ID, $data)
{

}

I assume the problem is originating with the
$images = $_POST[‘image_ids’];
$images = $_POST[‘gallery_image_ids’];
part of the code.

Can someone let me know what the correct meta field name for the gallery images is?

Comment: Well why don't you dump the value of `$data` and figure out the what key you are looking at.

Comment: isnt dumping data the value of the product not the POSTED value?

Comment: No,  $data
(array) Array of unslashed post data.  See : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/

Comment: oh i think i see what you mean, it would contain the meta field name of the POSTED data.  anyway I can see the dumped value of $data?  im relatively unfamiliar with woocommerce

Comment: Well the hook is of `wordpress` not woocommerce API.  What you can do is identify the value which you want to monitor for change. Get its value and if you see a diff trigger the email. As this action runs before saving the data you can check if it is chnaging or not.

Comment: $data was useless, no array of the gallery image ids

Comment: I dont think what I want to do is possible, because I suspect the gallery image ids are never submitted during the POST operation when the item is updated or saved.  I think they are only altered during the image attachment / upload for the product

Comment: Well, I guess it can be done. Which image are you exactly referring. If its a variation image it would be a different hook that you may need to try. If you aren't getting `$data` in this hook it means it is saving in the database through other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem…
I used a custom meta field to record the IDs for all the images, including the featured image then compared that to the current gallery images to see if they had changed, if they did then update the custom meta value with the new numbers and send an email to let people know the pictures changed.

code is as follows:

```
// send email when images change for a product
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'imagecheck_on_product_save', 10, 1 );
function imagecheck_on_product_save( $product_id ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    // do something with this product
    $metaImages = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_gallery_image_ids', true );
    $currentImages = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

$imageIDs = get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id );
if ($imagesIDs != "" )
{
    
$imageIDs = $imageIDs . ", ";
foreach($currentImages as $value){
    $imageIDs = $imageIDs . $value . ", "; 
}

if ( $metaImages != $imageIDs ) {
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_gallery_image_ids', esc_attr( $imageIDs ) );
    
    global $current_user;
            wp_get_current_user();
    $email = $current_user->user_email;
    $lastuser = $current_user->user_firstname;
    
    if ( $product->get_sku() != "" ) 
    {
        $memail = "<pre>USER: " . $lastuser . " made the following changes:</br>
Meta gallery images: " . $metaImages . "</br>
</br>
Actual gallery images: " . $imageIDs . "
" . $memail . "</pre>";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        $subject = "PICTURES CHANGED - SKU: " . $product->get_sku();
        $to = "(insert who you want to send to here)";
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $memail, $headers ); 
    }
}
}
}
```